# remove() in Arraylists of Arraylists not working

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm declaring the following two classes:

```
   public class formula
    {
    ArrayList<values> var= new ArrayList<values>;
}

public class values
{
    int val;
    void addval(int val1)
    {
        val=val1;
    }
}
```

I am declaring an ArrayList of type formula.

```
 ArrayList<formula> S= new ArrayList<formula>;
```

When I try to execute the following statement:

```
  S.get(i).var.remove(b);
```

where `i` is a loop variable

I don't get any error and it compiles fine, but doesn't delete the instance of `var(b)` for `formula(i)`. The value still remains. What is wrong? I am not using Iterators at all, just a loop to traverse through all the instances of `formula()`.

`b` is an integer. Essentially the index of the element in the var arraylist I'm trying to delete.

Comment: Most likely that you did not override hashCode and equals on values.  Didn't really post enough code to tell you for sure.

Comment: how does this works "public class formula()" ?

Comment: I guarantee you this does not compile "fine".

Comment: This seems to be a daily occurrence when I post snippets of code from my program.. @MarkPeters What's wrong?

Comment: @Floose: What does the compiler tell you is wrong?  I would hope that you would have tried to compile the snippet you're posting here.

Comment: `public class formula() {` should be `public class formula {`. Similar problem with the other class also. You also should follow the Java Naming Convention.

Comment: @Affe I didn't do any overriding.. haven't heard of it, actually. I tried removing an entire instance of formula through S.remove(i), and that worked fine.. So, I just don't get why I need to do overriding for this.

Comment: If you feel lazy to write code properly then you can just copy/paste it from your IDE. It's just about posting a compilable code if the issue is regarding code that at least runs.

Comment: @Floose: Give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  You left out what `b` is.  Is it an instance of `values` or an integer?

Comment: @BheshGurung : Sorry about that. It was a huge code and I just wanted to be concise.

Comment: @Mark Peters: I've edited the question to include what b is.. b is an integer.. the index of the element from var arraylist that I'm trying to delete. When I wanted to delete an element from S, I just did S.remove(i).. where i is the integer index of element, and it worked.. I didn't need to do any oveerriding or anything. Don't understand why that's the case for var alone. The compiler doesn't show any error.It just doesn't delete the element at index b in the var arraylist. That's all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must override equals and hashcode while using collection API's. Otherwise you will see lot of unpredictable results in your code...

If you are new to Java, make it a habit to override equals, hashcode and toString methods.

Answer (score 2):

If b = the key, it better be a **values** object. Here the object b should have the the same hashCode as the key and the equals() method should return true. In Java for two objects **obj1** and **obj2** to be be considered as the same, the following conditions should be satisfied.

1. obj1.hashCode()== obj2.hashCode()
2. obj1.equals(obj2)== true